# When modeling the magnetic field of an electromagnet array, how to take the interference between electromagnets into account?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

When it comes to the magnetic field of an electromagnet array, all the papers and books I've read will give this equation:
$$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{P})=\sum_{e=1}^{n}\mathbf{B}_{e}(\mathbf{P})=\sum_{e=1}^{n}\tilde{\mathbf{B}}_{e}(\mathbf{P})i_{e}$$

Where $\mathbf{P}$ is the target location for which you want to know about the magnetic field, $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{P})$ is the magnetic field, $\mathbf{B}_{e}(\mathbf{P})$ is the magnetic field produced by the $e$th electromagnet, $n$ is the total amount of the electromagnets, $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}_{e}(\mathbf{P})$ **is the magnetic field produced by** $e$**th electromagnet while it's driven by unit-current and all other electromagnets don't have currents passing through them** and finally, $i_{e}$ is the current in $e$th electromagnet. So in this model, you scale the unit-current magnetic field of each electromagnet with their respective currents, and add them together. And if one wants to know the currents needed to produce a certain $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{P})$ on a certain location $\mathbf{P}$, they could just calculate the pseudo-inverse of the matrix formed by $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}_{e}(\mathbf{P})$.

I have no problems with the first equality of the equation. However, I have questions for the second equality: **If the electromagnets in the array are relatively close to each other, when they're all actuated, wouldn't the magnetic fields from different electromagnets interfere with each other, thus making the magnetic field distribution produced by $e$th electromagnet $\mathbf{B}_{e}(\mathbf{P})$ different from when the $e$th electromagnet is the only one being actuated, causing $\mathbf{B}_{e}(\mathbf{P})$ no longer equal to $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}_{e}(\mathbf{P})i_{e}$? If they're indeed different and the second equality no longer holds, then what method should I use to model the magnetic field?** It could be either a numerical method or an analytical method, but I hope it isn't too complicated because my project requires rather fast calculation speed (less than 1s to get the currents).

The reason why I'm asking this is because of my project, in which I'm trying to manipulate the magnetic field created by an array of 13 electromagnets. The array looks like the picture below, with all the cylinders being my electromagnets. The inner space their end planes form is a hemi-spherical space with 100mm radius, and each electromagnet has 25mm radius and 50mm in length.

[image]

I tried to use the model described by the equation above. First, I measured the magnetic field of one electromagnet on different locations, and by interpolating the data, I was able to get the unit-current magnetic field map of one electromagnet $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}_{e}(\mathbf{P})$. Because by design, all the electromagnets have the same parameters, so I just assumed the unit-current magnetic field map was the same for every electromagnet. I also did some extra measurements to make sure my assumption is right and it turned out they did have very similar performance. Then, to manipulate the magnetic field, I simply pass a specific set of currents through the electromagnets. However, by measuring the magnetic field at my target point, I quickly found that the magnetic field is drastic smaller than what it should've been according to the equation above. Depending on the different target magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ and the different location of the target point $\mathbf{P}$, the actual magnitude of the magnetic field could go from 10% smaller to even 50% smaller than the theoretical value, and after a bit of troubleshooting, I suspect the incorrect modeling is the issue, and the reason why it is incorrect is because the electromagnets in my array are close to each other and that makes the model no longer eligible.

Comment: If you find a solution outside of the PSE forum, please share it here. So please answer your question yourself. Then everyone will learn something. (And me in particular :-)